# How can i add custom css and js in magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2.2

[image]

Please help me how can i add my custom abc.css and filename.js  in magento 2.2.2 .

`default_header_html.xml` file path

```
app/design/frontend/custom-theme/my-first-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_header_html.xml
```

my css path

```
app/design/frontend/custom-theme/my-first-theme/web/css/source/abc.css
```

my js path

```
app/design/frontend/custom-theme/my-first-theme/web/js/filename.js
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]app/design/frontend/vendorname/theme/web/css/custom.css

app/design/frontend/vendorname/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<css src="css/custom.css" order="100"/>

<script src="js/custom.js"/>
```

Comment: Hi saphal jha thanks for gave answer  but in above code not working..my xml file path is :  app/design/fronted/custom-theme/my-first-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_block.xml. my css path  is app/design/fronted/custom-theme/my-first-theme/web/css/custom.css

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below code

```
<css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom.css" />
<link src="Magento_Theme::js/custom.js"/>
```

Js File Path:

```
app\design\frontend\PackageName\ThemeName\Magento_Theme\web\js\custom.js
```

Css File Path:

```
app\design\frontend\PackageName\ThemeName\Magento_Theme\web\css\custom.css
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh Gosai thanks for gave answer  but in above code not working..

Comment: Have you cleared cache and deploy static content?

if not then run below commands

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Hi gosai  thanks for gave answer but in above code not working..my xml file path is : app/design/fronted/custom-theme/my-first-theme/Magento_Theme‌​/layout/default_head‌​_block.xml. my css path is app/design/fronted/custom-theme/my-first-theme/web/css/custo‌​m.css

Comment: Your css path is incorrect check my answer